# Magento2: Products group by filterable attributes

Tags: magento2, search, array, filtered-nav

Does anyone know how to get an array with the number of products grouped by attributes that can be filtered, in a controller o helper? For example:

```
["Activity" => [....], "GENDER" => ["MEN" => 5, "WOMEN" => 5, "UNISEX" => 1] ...]
```

[image]

i am trying to use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::getFilters()

but throw

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList;


class Magento extends Base {

protected $_filterList;

public function __construct(FilterList $filterList) {

    $this->_filterList = $filterList;

}
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface
> Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface in
> C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php:93
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(88):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Catalog...',
> Array) #1
> C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(130):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Catalog...')
>
> ## 2 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(67):
>
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\Catalog...')
>
> ## 3 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled.php(130):
>
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Catalog...')
>
> ## 4 C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Facto
>
> in
> C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php
> on line 93

Comment: Where do you want to get it?

Comment: In a controller

Answer (score 2):

You can get lsit of filters from `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::getFilters()`. Then you get array of all filters represented by objects extending from `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter`. Than on these objects (`Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\*`) you can call method `getItems()` which retrieves for you array of objects `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item`, representing each item option (take a note it may differ according to attribute setting - filterable with/no results). Also methdo `getItemsCount()` seems to be useful for you. Class `FilterList` you can add to you controller via DI and then use in `execute method`. Please not that array of filter don't have as array keys attibute codes of filterable attribute, but you can change it, attribute is available from filter model level.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface  why?

Comment: Didn't use that class, take a look on answer

Comment: i am using \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList but show that error...

Comment: tha exists in fact, as implemented interface for `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/Category/FilterableAttributeList`, but there should be no problem, have you tried clearing cache, di, generation and so on?

Comment: Yes but it does not work yet

Comment: post your code in question

Comment: ok is now available

Comment: for me it seems to be permission problem now - magento can't instantiate objects in /generation catalog - check your permissions against the documentation.

Comment: i am in windows... permissions??

Comment: i use  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList;

use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface; and works...

Comment: A yes, xampp, of course it is not a permissions thing. I don't know no. Try to make some plugins on this class and similiar which have methods like `getFilters()` etc.